# Docker network ls use --format to get only networks names

Tags: docker, networking, formatting, command-line-interface

I would like to get a list of networks names so I tried to do that with the command:

```
docker network ls --format "{{.Names}}"
```

but I got the error:

> Template parsing error: template: :1:2: executing "" at <.Names>:
> can't evaluate field Names in type *network.networkContext

I don't know why, especially `docker ps` produces output with the same column named `name` and works well with the format option:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}"
```

Is there any reference pointing the difference between formats these two commands accept and how to get just networks names from the `docker network ls` command by using the `--format` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker network ls --format "{{.Name}}"`: `Name`, not `Names`. I'm not sure why it's `Names` in the `docker ps` output, that seems inconsistent.

Comment: Back when Docker links were relevant, a container could have multiple names in the `docker ps` output (and correspondingly the Docker API) if it was linked to a different container.